# CSS "overflow-x:hidden" conflicts with browser Ctrl+F horizontal move off screen word highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, event-listener

**CSS Conflict**

```
html {overflow-x:hidden;}
```

with 

**Web Browser Command**

```
Ctrl + F  or find() or keyword search
```

**Problems:**

Site is horizontal scroll design that jumps to previous(Left) or next(Right) to a predetermined width/step/section without a visible horizontal scroll bar.

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
evt = evt || window.event;
switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
        leftArrowPressed();
        window.location.href = '#one';
        break;
    case 39:
        rightArrowPressed();
        window.location.href = '#two';
        break;
}
};
```

When I invoke a Ctrl+F to find words, the page will not follow the highlighter off screen left or right. Except when `Overflow-x: visible` and that only scrolls to the word not the entire screen width/step/section that the word is in.

- `Overflow-x:hidden;` removes the browsers ability to scroll horizontally;
- `Overflow-x:visible;` browsers only scrolls to word not next section when in horizontal overflow;

**Can I follow the browser ctrl+f word highlighter feature at predetermined width steps/sections?**

**Can I invoke the key-press when ctrl+f word highlighter moves off screen?**

**Is it possible to capture the highlighted word coordinates( x , y)?**


Functioning Test Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Alpha Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
html {
height:100%;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
body {
height:100%;
}
#wrap {
min-height:100%;
width:200%;
}
#one, #two {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            window.location.href = '#one';
            break;
        case 39:
            window.location.href = '#two';
            break;
    }
};
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">

<div id="one">
<iframe id="frame" src="https://wiki.videolan.org/" frameborder="0" marginwidth="" width="100%" height="100%" align="bottom">Browser not compatible.</iframe>
<!END URL-iFrame></div>

<div id="two">
<iframe id="frame" src="http://imdb.com" frameborder="0" marginwidth="" width="100%" height="100%" align="bottom">Browser not compatible.</iframe>
<!END URL-iFrame></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the overflow visible an option, if you would be able to fix the scroll position?

Comment: @t.niese Yes, if possible I want it removed. I can cover it with a fixed div if necessary.

Comment: with `overflow: visible` you could check if the `scroll` event is triggered and then check the `scrollLeft` if it has a valid value and if not correct it so that the page is fully visible. (I can't test myself right now, but this is what i would try)

Answer (score 2):

Overflow-x and overflow-y had always problems, even in the newest browsers. Both can have "hidden", "visible" and "scrollbar" ("auto" is only a combo of "visible" and "scrollbar"), which is thus 9 combinations.

But in the practice only 5 of them works, I reply: even in the newest Chrome! And what yet worser is: there is a difference between the browsers, which 5 is this...

Sometimes (in depends on your actual problem) a workaround is possible, if you combine overflow-x, overflow-y and overflow. Sometimes some JS-tricking is the solution. General and beautiful solution doesn't exist.

ctrl/f has with it probably nothing direct to do, it is an indirect cause of your problem, because the body of your page will be probably resized, when the search-widget of the browser appears. You could reproduce this problem probably with a vertical resize of the browser window, too.

Comment: Can you expand upon what the issues are, and which five of the combinations work?  Thanks!

Comment: @NealGokli Welcome on the SE! Uhm, this was 5 years ago, and I didn't worked in css too much since then :-(

Comment: Thanks anyway!  You are lucky to avoid css :)

Comment: @NealGokli Css is not so bad! Such edge cases are evil in it, you should avoid them and don't rule them!

Comment: @NealGokli Write a single page minimal html, and try it in different browsers! You need to learn the positioning only once, and everything will be okay after that.

Comment: I don't spend so much time on the web side of things, so I don't remember all the edge cases I come across.  And all the complex ways in which styles and attributes on different enclosing tags interact with each other.  And all the ways in which browsers are noncompliant.

I'm more of a backend guy!  Actually, I'm really more of a people person.  Nine more months and I'm off to grad school to become a psychotherapist!

Comment: @NealGokli You will likely have a good insight into the soul of the people need to solve practically insolvable problems in a fixed time. :-) My suggestion is: don't start to hack the css, particularly not with js. It is simply not enough. Not even today. Have a page layout which simply doesn't require such tricks. Look, how simple and good the SE looks, for example.

Comment: Thanks :)  Yes, I try to keep things as simple as I can manage (sometimes sacrificing development time, but it's worth it in the long run!)  I'm always simplifying the stuff I inherited :(